# Reattach the canvas context after using transferControlToOffscreen?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm playing about with a project at the moment where I have multiple simulations running in multiple web workers.

When I need to view the current state of the simulation I use transferControlToOffscreen on a canvas element in the main thread and pass the handle into a webworker.

The problem is the next time I try to use transferControlToOffscreen or just pass the existing handle into a different web worker the browser complains that I can't reclone the canvas.

```
An OffscreenCanvas could not be cloned because it was detached
```

Is there a function I need to call to reattach the canvas before using transferControlToOffscreen again?

---

Edit: It also seems like I can't pass the offscreenCanvas between the workers using a MessageChannel.

Is my only option to nullify the handle to the canvas is WorkerA, replace the current canvas (in the main thread) with a new one (Maybe cloned) and then send a new offscreenCanvas to worker B?

Comment: I think you could use `OffscreenCanvasRenderingContext2D#commit` to replace content of the original canvas with what's in the offscreen canvas context (be it "2d" or "webgl").

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So it turns out that the only solution to this was cloning the canvas, replacing it in the DOM with its own clone, and then using transferControlToOffscreen on the clone

Comment: Just curious, did you try sending the OffscreenCanvas from the worker back to the main thread, then having the main thread use that and/or pass that to another worker?

Comment: @trusktr How would you do that? There is no `transferControlToOnscreen` to mirror `-Offscreen`. There is no way to return control to the main thread. Looks like a glaring API omission!

Answer (score 1):

I found that this is occurred when invoking worker.postMessage with the offscreen variable directly (`worker.postMessage({canvas: offscreen}, offscreen)`) and is fixed by just turning the transfer variable into an array: `worker.postMessage({canvas: offscreen}, [offscreen])`.